# How to incorporate a case statement into a query with an aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this SQL which is failing because incidentdate in the case statement is not part of a group by or aggregate function. If I grouped by incidentdate then I would make the aggregate function useless as it will have a separate row for every difference in time.

So what I want to do is group by the results of that case statement, ie 'Days' or 'Nights', I have a fairly rubbish solution which is to put the data into a temp table then select from the temp table with the aggregate functions included but I believe there must be a better way.

What I want seems to be logically similar to a having clause but for use in the select.

```
SELECT    
    d.DeptName,
    CASE
       WHEN DATEPART(hh, nmm.incidentdate) < 6 OR 
            DATEPART(hh, nmm.incidentdate) >= 18 
          THEN 'Nights'
       WHEN DATEPART(hh, nmm.incidentdate) >= 6 AND 
            DATEPART(hh, nmm.incidentdate) < 18 
          THEN 'Days'
    END AS [Shift],
    COUNT(nmm.ReferenceNo)
FROM 
    NearMissesMain nmm
INNER JOIN
    Departments d ON d.DepartmentID = nmm.reporterdepartment 
WHERE
    nmm.DepartmentID = 1
GROUP BY 
    d.DeptName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a derived table. If you think about what you are asking SQL to do, you are looking at potentially multiple dates, that could be Nights or Days but wanting that on one row. You could have both Nights and Days for the same reference no. Not tested the below, so apologies if it isn't perfect, but hopefully it gives you the idea:

```
SELECT      A.DeptName              ,
            A.[Shift]               ,
            COUNT(A.ReferenceNo)

FROM
(
        SELECT      d.DeptName,
                    CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, nmm.incidentdate) < 6 or DATEPART(hh, nmm.incidentdate) >= 18 then 'Nights'
                        WHEN DATEPART(hh, nmm.incidentdate) >= 6 and DATEPART(hh, nmm.incidentdate) < 18 then 'Days'
                        END AS [Shift],
                    nmm.ReferenceNo
        FROM        NearMissesMain nmm
        INNER JOIN  Departments d on d.DepartmentID = nmm.reporterdepartment 
        WHERE       nmm.DepartmentID = 1
)   AS  A
GROUP BY    A.DeptName  ,
            A.[Shift]
```

Comment: This works, and saves using temp tables.. thanks! I was thinking there may be a cleverer way of doing this without a subquery but i'll accept this.

Comment: You could potentially use the case statement in the group by, just to get the nights and days out of there also. That would avoid the derived table.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add below in group by as well:

```
group by d.DeptName,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH, NMM.INCIDENTDATE) < 6 OR DATEPART(HH, NMM.INCIDENTDATE) >= 18 THEN 'NIGHTS'
WHEN DATEPART(HH, NMM.INCIDENTDATE) >= 6 AND DATEPART(HH, NMM.INCIDENTDATE) < 18 THEN 'DAYS'
END
```

is sufficient

Comment: This doesn't work as I just want to group by Days or Nights, what you suggest groups by every second difference in incidentdate.

Comment: Just noticed your date part of hour.. Thank